# Example of same Preorder and Postorder traversal?

Tags: algorithm

If only the root node is present then preorder and postorder traversal will be the same i.e root node only. What are other examples in which preorder and postorder traversal will be the same?

Comment: None.  If the root has any children, then preorder will visit them after the root and postorder will visit them before.  So they can only be the same if there are no children.

Comment: or if all node values are the same

Comment: Post and pre-order are trivially the same for any empty structure. I.e. no node at all.

Comment: @Sunil kumar Do you need a few examples or a general rule to generate such trees?

Comment: @GauravSingh thanku ...you cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be tree like :
           a
           /   \
           b       c
       /            \
     a                a

Preorder, postorder and inorder traversal : a b a c a

Comment: This solution assumes an equivalence relation on the nodes though.

Comment: @michid This is just one of many (possibly infinite) such trees. I just tried to give one example which wasn't covered in the comments to the question.

Comment: what I was trying to say is that in the question there is no mention of when nodes are considered equal. Without any further assumption to that  respect every node is just equal to itself.